# Force placed Legend into one column

Tags: plotting, legending, column

I have a complicated plot (originally a ListLogPlot using many options) with now twelve curves and I would like to force the legend to be displayed in one single column.

Here, I tried to formulate a simplified example:

```
Plot[{Log[x], Log[x + 1], Log[x + 2], Log[x + 3], Log[x + 4], 
Log[x + 5], Log[x + 6], Log[x + 7], Log[x + 8], Log[x + 9], 
  Log[x + 10], Log[x + 11]}, {x, 0, 30}, PlotTheme -> {"Detailed"}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 30}, {0, 5}}, LabelStyle -> {Small, Black}, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[{"0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", 
    "11"}, {{0.7, 0.1}, {0, 0}}]]
```

this produces the following picture
[image]

To my understanding enough space would be available to avoid the second column. And in my original plot the legend consists of a longer description, hence a second column isn't readable anymore.

I assume something like
`LegendStyle->{"Column",1}`
would be part of the solution. But I wasn't able to get it working in connection with the usage of `Placed`.

Any ideas and help are very much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are almost there. Use a `LineLegend` instead.

```
Plot[
 {Log[x], Log[x + 1], Log[x + 2], Log[x + 3], Log[x + 4], Log[x + 5], 
  Log[x + 6], Log[x + 7], Log[x + 8], Log[x + 9], Log[x + 10], 
  Log[x + 11]
  }, {x, 0, 30}
 , PlotTheme -> {"Detailed"}
 , PlotRange -> {{0, 30}, {0, 5}}
 , LabelStyle -> {Small, Black}
 , ImageSize -> 600
 , PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[LineLegend[
    ColorData[97][#] & /@ Range[12] {"0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", 
      "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11"}
    , LegendLayout -> {"Column", 1}
    , LegendMarkerSize -> 10
    ], {{0.95, 0.33}}
   ]
 ]
```

[image]

**EDIT**

Experiment with `LegendFunction` and adjust other options accordingly.

```
LegendFunction -> (Framed[#, Background -> White, RoundingRadius -> 4,
     FrameStyle -> LightGray] &)
```

`LegendLayout -> {"ReversedColumn", 1}` would make the legend easier to follow.

Comment: Perfect! This was exactly what I looked for. I use it with a ```ListLogPlot```, hence I didn't dare to use ```LineLegend``` , but it works.

Comment: I am glad I was able to help you. Thanks for the accept.